# Copy/Paste in the cell below

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I would simply like to copy and paste the numbers included in column 2 and 3 in the ligne below IF and only IF the first 4 digits of the string in column 1 in line n+1 is equal to the first 4 digits of the string line n --> 50231 for example

Here is my code:

```
function myFunction() {

 var feuilleVERIF = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CR-MR')
 var lastRow = feuilleVERIF.getLastRow();
 tableau = feuilleVERIF.getRange('A10:N');
 for (i=0; i < tableau.length + lastRow; i++){
   var PARAM = tableau[i][3].substring(0,6);

   if ( tableau[i+1][0].substring(0,6) == PARAM){
     var CoeffA = tableau[i][4].getValues();
     var CoeffB = tableau[i][5].getValues();

     CoeffA.copyTo(tableau[i+1][4])
     CoeffB.copyTo(tableau[i+1][5])
   }
 } 
}
```

[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19sND.png)

Comment: You cannot treat the range as an array.  You have to use the getValues() method to access values

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('CR-MR')
  vs = sh1.getRange('A10:N' + sh1.getLastRow());
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs)):
  for (i = 0; i < vs.length; i++) {
    if (i < vs.length - 1) {
      var PARAM = vs[i][3].substring(0, 6);
      if (vs[i + 1][0].substring(0, 6) == PARAM) {
        var a = vs[i][4];
        var b = vs[i][5];
        sh1.getRange(i + 10, 4, 1, 2).setValues([[a, b]]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, it still doesn't return anything..

Comment: Let me know was the logger is capturing

Comment: The code ran successfully, nothing wrong happened..

Comment: But I have no data in the cells above..

Comment: Did you check the execution log

Comment: 5:07:38 PM Notice Execution started
5:07:39 PM Info {}
5:07:39 PM Notice Execution completed

Comment: Hello, here is the log (I think it says nothing appears in the Range..)

Comment: Can you please share a table of data.  Please no images.  I wan't something I can copy and paste and keep in mind I will not follow links to spreadsheets

Comment: I posted a set of simples values below in answer, thanks

Comment: 5023450 0,0076295105    -100,00
5023451     

5024450 0,9753827745    -32 069,23
502445F     

5025450 -2,7683         90740,00
5025451

Comment: Can you do something for me?

Comment: That's not much test data considering you data range is 14 columns wide and probably several lines long.

Comment: I don't understand how it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you please help me? the set of values is below, thank you so much!

Comment: Perhaps you can share you spreadsheet because you code suggests that your data is 13 columns wide and your data is not in a table so it does not paste well and I don't know what it's supposed to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can use to help solve this pb.
You can use this set of values to copy/paste in a file and watch what the log show us: we have 3 columns

```
5023450 0,0076295105    -100,00
5023451     

5024450 0,9753827745    -32 069,23
502445F     

5025450 -2,7683         90740,00
5025451
```